# Unable to Build Docker Image for Spring Boot No such property: parentFile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am trying to build a sample docker image for my helloworld program

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.DockerBuildImage

plugins {
    id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '6.7.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

task createDockerfile(type: Dockerfile) {
    destFile = project.file('build/docker/Dockerfile')
    from 'openjdk:8-jre-alpine'
    copyFile "libs/${jar.archiveBaseName}-${jar.archiveVersion}.jar", "${jar.archiveBaseName}.jar"
    entryPoint 'java'
    defaultCommand '-jar', "${jar.archiveBaseName}.jar"
    exposePort 8080
}


task buildImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    dependsOn createDockerfile
    inputDir = createDockerfile.destFile.parentFile
    tag = "${jar.archiveBaseName}:latest"
}
```

Its giving me this error

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parentFile for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultRegularFileVar
    at build_dawchkdhtqfn2zzdavoge0cnm$_run_closure5.doCall(/Users/mchavak/Downloads/demo/build.gradle:45)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:666)
    at org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.configure(DefaultTask.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.task(DefaultProject.java:1294)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:135)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:84)
    at build_dawchkdhtqfn2zzdavoge0cnm.run(/Users/mchavak/Downloads/demo/build.gradle:43)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put something else to **inputDir** like `inputDir = file('docker/myapp')`
https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/current/user-guide/